# Webpack: Throw error on missing member import

Tags: webpack

I have an import something like this:

```
import { foo } from 'bar';
```

Is there a way to get Webpack to throw an error if `foo` is not defined?

*Note that I'm using Babel if that makes a difference.*

Comment: Webpack is plain javascript. if(!foo) throw new Error('someError');

Comment: I was more meaning automatically. I have had cases where I have mis-spelt `foo` and it has taken me awhile to realise what the issue is. Seeing as webpack has to "import" it I assume it would know if it is defined or not?

Comment: I'd like this too. Not sure if this is relevant: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1729

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Tobias K pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539768/webpack-throw-error-on-missing-member-import#comment72235672_42155958), the other answer is incorrect. Configuring `strictModuleExceptionHandling: true` will not produce a compile time error if you try to import a module which does not exist.

The correct configuration is `strictExportPresence: true`, which is only available in webpack v2.3.0 and later. (Earlier versions can only show a warning, not an error.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to configure webpack 2 to throw an error when an import fails by using `output.strictModuleExceptionHandling`. The functionality was added by this pull request https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/3302 but it has not been documented yet. Here's how to use it:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./main.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        strictModuleExceptionHandling: true
    }
}
```

Now if I try to import from a file which dosn't exist, or I make an import which resolves to `undefined` I would get error and warning messages in the webpack console:

```
WARNING in ./js/pedigree.js
32:35-49 "export 'default' (imported as 'DisorderLegend') was not found in './disorderLegend'

ERROR in ./js/pedigree.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './OkCancelDialogue' in '/home/tim/workspace/projects/public/js/ext-lib/panogram/js'
 @ ./js/pedigree.js 5:0-54
 @ ./js/viewerPedigree.js
 @ ./main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./main.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

In the chrome console you'll get a warning like this:

[image: warning message in chrome]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm still getting `WARNING in ./a.js
2:0-1 "export 'c' was not found in './b'` (webpack 2.2.1).

Comment: The config is enabling the warning message - you still have to fix the imports yourself

Comment: It's not. The warning message is there regardless to `strictModuleExceptionHandling` option.

Comment: Do you also get the warnings about undefined imports?

Comment: please see the image at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, I was waiting to try this out myself before I marked it as answered. Oddly I can't seem to get it to work, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. All you added was `strictModuleExceptionHandling: true` to output right? And then did something like `import test from 'existing-file';`? I'm on Webpack v2.2.1.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got those errors to display but according to [this commit](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/959/files) that isn't the purpose for strictModuleExceptionHandling :/

Comment: `strictModuleExceptionHandling` is not correct here. webpack 2.3 will add `strictExportPresence` which has the expected behavior. see also https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/4348