# Webpack 4.x does not tell me when an import is undefined

Tags: webpack

Using Webpack 4.12

If I attempt to import something from a module, where the module exists, but the thing I'm trying import doesn't, webpack makes no mention of it.

For instance, if I try to do either one of these (either with harmony or commonjs):

```
import {shouldnotwork} from 'core-js';
const {shouldnotwork} = require('core-js');
```

Then, Webpack just carries on like there is no issue. In these cases, `shouldnotwork` will be `undefined`.

Meanwhile, in my huge site with tons of files, all of the pages and features that use that component will simply not work, at runtime. Naturally I won't realize this unless I actually try to use each feature of my site.

So, I've attempted to use `strictModuleExceptionHandling`, [which someone suggested online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539768/webpack-throw-error-on-missing-member-import?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```
In webpack.config.js
config.output = {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js', 
    strictModuleExceptionHandling: true
};
```

This did absolutely nothing. Did I use it wrong?

I also considered trying to use `strictExportPresence`, [which someone had suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539768/webpack-throw-error-on-missing-member-import?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But [according to their documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-contexts), it's deprecated and will be removed.

What I want, is for Webpack to print something to the console that alerts me when I attempt to import something that does not exist (and results in undefined).

I'm used to this functionality, because my current Gulp.js + Browserify build system takes no prisoners. I want to switch to Webpack, but this is a massive show stopper until I can achieve the same level of quality control I already have.

So, what can I do to make this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost I had to tell Babel to error on missing imports, by setting `modules: false` in the webpack-preset-env configuration. This caused Webpack to raise warnings.

Secondly, setting `config.module.strictExportPresence = true` turned those warnings into compilation errors.